# DataTableReader check if have next result c#

Tags: c#, ado.net, recordset

Hello guys I am with a problem that I need to check if a DataTableReader object has more results on the next time I call `Read()` function.
My code is like that:

```
        DataTable workTable = new DataTable();
        workTable.Columns.Add("1");
        workTable.Columns.Add("2");
        DataRow workRow;

        for (int i = 0; i <= 9; i++)
        {
            workRow = workTable.NewRow();
            workRow[0] = i;
            workRow[1] = "CustName" + i.ToString();
            workTable.Rows.Add(workRow);
        }
        var test2 = workTable.CreateDataReader();

        while (test2.Read())
        {
            Debug.WriteLine(test2[1]);
            //I need to know if the test2 instance Read function
            //will return false next time I call it without move the current
            //cursor..
            Debug.WriteLine("Have next?: "+ test2.HasNextResult()); //something like that, of some workaround...
        }
```

Is there anyway to do that??

Just for you guys know, I am doing that because I am mocking (for unity test) a COM record set object that has the `EOF` property and the `MoveNext` method. The `EOF` check if the current row is empty, and the `MoveNext` method moves the current cursor to the next record, and I am using an instance of `DataTableReader` to override these operations.

Answer (score 0):

The datatablereader has a NextResult method that will return a Boolean based on whether or not the reader has more results.

you can use it as such

```
do
{
  var x = reader.Read();
  ...Rest of your code
} while (reader.NextResult());
```

Comment: This solution did not work. Just passed throught one time, and then left the `do{}while` statement. The `NextResult` method returned false, but I have added 9 items (as the code shows in my question description)